# How to use custom field in react admin, insted of { data: [...] }

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm new in react-admin and I'm trying to create a new admin panel for my old API.
So when my data provider do API calls it causes me this error:

```
The response to 'getList' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getList'
```

The responses of my old API has various data fields like { 'posts': [] } or { 'users': [] }. How can I use these name of fields instead of { 'data': [] } ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' in this case just refers to the type of information that should be retuned, not the name of the object.

Within your API, you can simply return a list in the following form:

```
   const posts = [
        {
           "id":1,
           "name":"post1"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "name":"post2"
        },

   ];

return JSON.stringify(posts);
```

Then return that 'posts' object in your response and don't forget to set the expected ContentRange headers.

Not sure what language you are using, but the principle above should be easy enough to follow and apply in any language.